# Vuetify- Maintain row index in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-data-table containing items like this

```
<v-data-table :items="items" ...>
 <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
   <td>{{props.index}}</td>
   <td>{{props.name}}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

There are more than 20 items, i am trying to maintain row index. When i use `props.index`, it is displaying 0-5 all the time, even though if i change the pagination. How to maintain that incremental index even thought if i change the pagination?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you will have `pagination.sync` to local data attribute, then you can calculate the current index as

```
(pagination.page - 1)* pagination.rowsPerPage + props.index
```

Your pagination object:

```
{
  descending: boolean
  page: number
  rowsPerPage: number // -1 for All
  sortBy: string
  totalItems: number
}
```

[Demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/VqZqLd)

Comment: Thanks you, and is this possible to maintain the index on the top of headers. I am trying to maintain custom headers using `<template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">`, here i don't see any props.index. How can i maintain the same index on top.